# redirect subdomain to another domain

Tags: redirect, subdomain

Current i am using windows shared hosting. I need to redirect my sub domain to a new domain(including the entire path).

For example, when user visit to http://oldsubdomain.olddomain.com/page1/topic1 , it will redirect user to http://newdomain.com/page1/topic1

This is the method suggest by my service provider

```
<script language="c#" runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.new-url.com");
}
</script>
```

But this way seems like not able to redirect the entire url. Any suggestions?
Thanks

*UPDATE

Trying to redirect using web.config as below, but still get 500 Internal error, any idea?

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rule name="CName to URL" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)\.olddomain\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://newdomain.com/{R:0}" />
      </rule>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
    <system.web>      
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the redirect method?

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   response.redirect("http://newdomain.com/page1/topic1");
}
```

Comment: Hi, i cannot hardcoded the url path. For example, when user search the link via search engine, i need to redirect the particular url to the new domain together with entire path.